# Toggle button seems not have css

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular6, ng-bootstrap

I need to create a dropdown button, so I installed bootstrap and ng-boostrap. This is my html:

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my app.module.ts I put:

```
imports:{
    NgbModule.forRoot()}
```

I have just also put bootstrap css in my angular.json file.

The problem is that dropdown appear grey like it doesn't have css. I don't know what is the problem. Anyone can help me?

EDIT
My angular.json file have this:

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. May be you haven't included bootstrap css file. Can you try to test if css rules are applied using inspect element option in chrome browser.

Comment: I edit my question with my file

Comment: You need to [put your button](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/buttons/examples) in `<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">` to use toggle button. You can't give your button _btn_ class without put the button in a group first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1) install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

`npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

Step 2) Import the ng-bootstrap package in app.module.ts file

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [NgbModule, ...],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Note: No need of doing **NgbModule.forRoot()**

Step 3) Use your html code in app.component.html file

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have created the same example, which is forked from the ng-bootstrap.
[View Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-botstrap-dropdown)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I'll add a Step 4). Install bootstrap.css using: npm install bootstrap-css-only, and add node_modules/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.css to angular.json file

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding line:

```js
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

to my **/src/styles.css** file.

(You need have bootstrap or bootstrap-css-only installed. To install run command `npm install bootstrap-css-only --save`)